# Datepicker Range Javascript y Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, datepicker

Intento utilizar la herramienta de `DatePicker` de http://www.daterangepicker.com/ en mi proyecto `Django` deseo que la fecha ingresada por el usuario se envié con método `POST` a mi vista, el problema consiste en que no se nada de `javascript` y esto es lo que tengo en mi `HTML`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({

        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY '
        },
        ranges: {
           'Hoy': [moment(), moment()],
           'Ayer': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Ultimos 7 dias': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Ultimos 30 dias': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Este Mes': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Mes pasado': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]

        }

    });


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
      }
      });

    });


    </script>





 <form action="{% url 'subestados' %}" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label>Rango:  </label>
            <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Tengo entendido que hay una manera con `AJAX` de enviar con método `post` con un código parecido a este:

```
function(start, end, label) {
    $.post("url",
    {
       "start":start,
       "end": end
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data sent);
    });

}
```

Pero no se como implementarlo. 
¿Alguna idea ?

Comment: Hola, si claro, mira esta pregunta como guía https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022195/date-range-picker-send-selected-date-with-ajax ,  en la url tendrás algo como  /fechas/,  que apuntaran a tu url donde tendras alguna API Rest, o Apiview, para que reciba el post.

Comment: Lo siento no entendi

Comment: @Mariano gracias por el dato lo voy a tomar en cuenta para las proximas ediciones